# How can I know if Object is String type object?

Tags: java

I have to know if `Object` is String or any other class type, how can I do it? Currently I do it like below, but its not very good coding.

```
try {
    String myString = (String) object;
    // do stuff here
} catch(Exception e) {
    // it wasn't string, so just continue
}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
 object instanceof Type
```

is `true` if the object is a `Type` or a subclass of `Type`

```
 object.getClass().equals(Type.class)
```

is `true` only if the object is a `Type`

Answer (score 29):

Use the `instanceof` syntax.

Like so:

```
Object foo = "";

if( foo instanceof String ) {
  // do something String related to foo
}
```

Comment: I think this response is better because it considers null value, contrary to the solution above which can raise an exception.

Answer (score 13):

Guard your cast with `instanceof`

```
String myString;
if (object instanceof String) {
  myString = (String) object;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From JDK 14+ which includes [JEP 305](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305) we can do Pattern Matching for `instanceof`

Patterns basically test that a value has a certain type, and can extract information from the value when it has the matching type.

*Before Java 14*

```
if (obj instanceof String) {
    String str = (String) obj; // need to declare and cast again the object
    .. str.contains(..) ..
}else{
     str = ....
}
```

*Java 14 enhancements*

```
if (!(obj instanceof String str)) {
    .. str.contains(..) .. // no need to declare str object again with casting
} else {
    .. str....
}
```

We can also combine the type check and other conditions together

```
if (obj instanceof String str && str.length() > 4) {.. str.contains(..) ..}
```

The use of pattern matching in `instanceof` should reduce the overall number of explicit casts in Java programs.

**PS**: `instanceOf` will only match when the object is not null, then only it can be assigned to `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `instanceof` or method `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`.

Comment: Are these two options the same or do they have any subtle differences?

Comment: @jocull Yes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

javamonkey79 is right. But don't forget what you might want to do (e.g. try something else or notify someone) if object is not an instance of String.

```
String myString;
if (object instanceof String) {
  myString = (String) object;
} else {
  // do something else     
}
```

BTW: If you use ClassCastException instead of Exception in your code above, you can be sure that you will catch the exception caused by casting object to String.  And not any other exceptions caused by other code (e.g. NullPointerExceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you don't need to know depending on what you are doing with it.

```
String myString = object.toString();
```

or if object can be null

```
String myString = String.valueOf(object);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer op's question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use typeof(object) to compare against