# Code for checking a variable is a string or a boolean

Tags: java

I am getting values from an excel sheet and I need to find for each cell if values are varchar, String or boolean, then I need to validate and then I need to insert.
How can I check if `sRow.get(0)` is String or not?

```
System.out.println("valuesss::"+sRow.get(0));
myInsertStatement.setString(1, sRow.get(0));
myInsertStatement.setString(2, sRow.get(1));
myInsertStatement.setString(3, sRow.get(2));
myInsertStatement.setString(4, sRow.get(3));
myInsertStatement.setString(5, sRow.get(4));
myInsertStatement.setString(6, sRow.get(5));
myInsertStatement.setDate(7, sd1);
myInsertStatement.setDate(8, sd2);
myInsertStatement.setInt(9, (new Double(Double.parseDouble(sRow.get(8)))).intValue());
myInsertStatement.setString(10, sRow.get(9));
```

Comment: maybe here is your problem solved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344871/how-can-i-know-if-object-is-string-type-object

Answer (score 1):

you can use `instanceof` for example `if(sRow.get(0) instanceof String)`

Comment: checking date format

Comment: String a= ''true" then you can use this to get type of variable and use if..else to make your logic for Boolean and string a.getClass().getName()

Comment: sRow.get(0) i am getting three values how can i check each value

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache POI library to read the excel cell value

```
 switch (cell.getCellType()) {
       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        break;
    }
```