# Mapping wild card Function interface to a typed Function interface

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, functional-interface

I have a number of accessor methods that interrogate various objects and return a Function<Context, ?>, like such:

```
  public static Function<ExmonMessageCtx, Optional<?>> reason() {
    return ctx ->
        ctx.getThing().map(Thing::getReason);
  }
```

The ultimate type of these accessor methods is either a String or Long but that could expand to different types.

I also have a "master" accessor method like such:

```
  public static Function<Context, Optional<?>> masterAccessor(String name) {
      switch (name) {
      case "reason":
          return reason();
      case "destination":
          return destination():
          ...
      default:
          return ctx -> Optional.empty():
    }
```

What I would like to be able to do is to take this master accessor function and apply another function such that it will return a Function<Context, Optional> if, for example, I want to map it against Strings. If the particular name given actually would result in one of the field accessors that uses a Long, it would return an Optional.empty().

So, what I am trying to figure out is how to make that type mapping method.

I've tried to create a mapping method like this

```
public static Function<Context, Optional<String>> stringType(String name, Optional<?> value) {
      switch (name) {
      case "reason":
      case "destination":
      ...
          return ctx -> Optional.of((String) value.get());
      default:
          return ctx -> Optional.empty();
      }
}
```

but then I'm not sure how to apply it to the master accessor function. Obviously, I'm still trying to understand this functional programming approach so I'm sure I'm failing to grasp something inherit to this, but that's why I'm here. Maybe this approach is wrong but my mandate here is that the masterAccessor method should not really change and I definitely shouldn't have different master accessors for each type (like a stringMasterAccessor and longMasterAccessor).

Edit: I want to end up with a function that I can pass in to a method like the one below:

```
  public static Predicate<Context> stringEquals(
      Function<Context, Optional<String>> accessor, String str) {
    return predicate(accessor, val -> str.equals(val));

  public static <T> Predicate<Context> predicate(
      Function<Context, Optional<T>> accessor, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return msg -> accessor.apply(msg).map(v -> predicate.test(v)).orElse(false);
```

}
}

Comment: What is the return type of `Thing::getReason`? I guess by modelling the type as `Optional<?>` you are losing out on the type info. Is your goal just to check if the underlying value of the optional a String? Does this help [How can I know if Object is String type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344871/how-can-i-know-if-object-is-string-type-object)?

Comment: To add to my earlier point, since you are returning a Function, you won't know if the type of the value (i.e., checking if the Object represented by the wildcard `?`) is String until you invoke the function.

Comment: We might be having a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A context has a `Thing` and it has various fields like reason, destination etc., (you haven't specified their types). Starting with this, what is your problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Thiyagu So, right now, those fields can either be a String or Long, but might eventually become more types. I think I want to have a Function<Context, Optional<?>> and transform it to Function<Context, Optional<String>> based on a mapper method, such that in a different method I can pass in the Function<Context, Optional<String>>. The reasons for this are somewhat more complex than I can really encompass here, but that is the crux of the problem. I'm adding in to the example of the method I want to be able to pass a function into.

Comment: Can you explore if you can do the type checking at the place where you invoke the function? Pass the result of `accessor.apply(msg)` to some function and there you check if the result is of the required type. If not, you can return back an empty Optional.

Comment: I think I can sort of see how that might work. I will dig into that soon and see if I can figure it out.